# jquery selector problem

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

From firebug:

```
>>> $("form#commentform").serialize();
"username=&email=&comment=&verify="
>>> $("#commentform").serialize();
""
>>> $("form#commentform")
[form#commentform]
>>> $("#commentform")
[div#commentform]
>>> $("#commentform").length
1
```

This is really weird,`form#commentform` works,but `#commentform` doesn't,why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two elements with the id `commentform`.
This is invalid. `$('#commentform')` returns only the first one, which cannot be serialized.

From the [specs](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/id#id):

> Matches a single element with the given id attribute.

Comment: That is exactly the point - it assumes there's only one item. Under the hood, btw, it is using `getElementById`, which returns a single element.